# Ionic Media Player

Tags: html, ionic-framework, media-player

I'm building an application using Ionic v3 that runs media (*.mp3, *.mp4) on a tablet where the data resides on an external microsd.

1. When I used HTML5, I couldn't have the microsd access the "file:///storage/emulated/0 ...etc", however, it works perfectly fine when accessing a file over the internet. I guess i can't have it working from a microsd since HTML5 cannot access a local file. Is it true? or is there another way around?
2. When I used Ionic VideoPlayer plugin, there is no way where i can play the video inside a div. I need to play the media in a div so i can hide it when an mp3 is playing and show it only for mp4. however I can play the file with no issues from the micorsd ("file:///storage/emulated/0 ...etc")
3. Is it possible to have an iframe pointing to a local page generated by the ionic application? 
   example: `<iframe src='TestPage' width='50%' height='50%'></iframe>`

Is there a plugin that i can use where i can pause/start/control volume/resize and play media from microsd installed on a tablet other then the ones stated above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check on this plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/ i am sure it will help solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the Media Plugin. I need it to support video too (mp4). All I read was about audio. Does it support video too?

Comment: yushin, how will i place the video in a div or control the height and width of it when running?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to. since this is a plugin i doubt if you can have access to setting the dimensions